# How to delete data from firebase android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I faced an issue when I had to delete that data which user entered in here this photo. If the user entered enrollment number `60` then I have to delete all data from marks where the enrollment number is `60`.

[image]

It deletes the data which user entered and it verifies that enrollment from marks and delete all data where enrollment is `66` it means delete that document or node.

I tried the following that did not work.

`reff.child("Marks").removeValue().equals(et1);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code.

```
int enrollmentId = Integer.parseInt( et1.getText().toString() );
reff.child("Marks").orderByChild("enrollment").equalTo(enrollmentId)
.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) 
                {
                    for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                    {
                        ds.getRef().removeValue(); 
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) 
                {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Failed to delete", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                });
```

Comment: it gave following error ```Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.child(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference```

Comment: the  `reff` in an object of `DatabaseRefference` and it initialized in your onCreate() method.
am i right?

Comment: `et1` is a String or an object?

Comment: yes `    reff=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214937/discussion-between-dharmik-and-mufazmi).

Answer (score 1):

To delete data do the following:

```
DatabaseReference data = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Marks");
data.orderByChild("enrollment").equalTo("66").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
         @Override
      public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
      for(DataSnapshot data: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
            data.getRef().removeValue();

                  }

            }
        @Override
       public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

               }
          });
```

Add a reference to child `Marks` then using the query `orderByChild` you can get the correct node and delete it

Comment: What do you mean

Comment: i mean by if i am putting this code on click listener nothing be happens...application run successfully but clicking on button nothing be happen...

Comment: @Dharmik use `equalTo(66)` without quotations also add a log to check if it is entering the method or not

Comment: i got my answer thanks for u r help! u r answer is also right  but not so match as my question

Answer (score 0):

```
    String et1 =e1.getText().toString().trim();
                    reff.child("Marks").orderByChild("enrollment").equalTo(et1)
                            .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
                                {
                                    for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                                    {
                                        ds.getRef().removeValue();
                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError)
                                {
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed to delete", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            });
```